# How change youtube android API language according app language

Tags: android, youtube-api

Does anyone know how YouTube Android Player API choose the language for displaying connection error message ??

I´m trying to display the error message according the app language.
These messages are shown according the device language by default, but I need an alternative to show them with the same application language

Furthermore, I want personalize these messages.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do that but you can try to specify the **language** and **region** on you query to the api, ex:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&order=date&regionCode=RU&type=video&videoCategoryId=23&lr=ru_RU&key={KEY}

in this case the language is Russian `lr=ru_RU` and the country Russia `regionCode=RU`

list of available options for language and regions

```
var lang_list = {"en_US": 0, "en_GB": 1, "zh_CN": 2, "zh_TW": 3, "es_ES": 4, "es_MX": 5, "ja_JP": 6, "pt_PT": 7, "pt_BR": 8, "de_DE": 9, "ar_EG": 10, "fr_FR": 11, "ru_RU": 12, "ko_KR": 13};

var reg_lang_code =(en_US|en_GB|zh_CN|zh_TW|es_ES|es_MX|ja_JP|pt_PT|pt_BR|de_DE|ar_EG|fr_FR|ru_RU|ko_KR)
```

Comment: Thanks Tuga, It might work.

what about custom error messages?